# BST: Pointers after rotation

Tags: java, pointers, rotation, binary-search-tree

I am trying to solve a puzzle but i can't find the right way to deal with it.
In a Binary Search Tree, i am using rotations to push a node to the bottom (leaf). 
Here is the code.

```
    TreeNode rotateright(TreeNode node){
        TreeNode temp= node.left;
        node.left = temp.right;
        temp.right = node;
        return node;
    }

    TreeNode rotateleft(TreeNode node){
        TreeNode temp = node.right;
        node.right = temp.left;
        temp.left = node; 
        return node;
    }
```

The problem is that when the node starts moving downwards, it's original parent keeps pointing at him
and by the time i delete that node its whole subtree disappears.
Have a look at the code:

```
        while (node.left!=null){
            lastnode=node.left;
            rotateright(node);
        }
        while (node.right!=null){
            lastnode=node.right;
            rotateleft(node);
        }
        if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(lastnode.item.keyword)<0)lastnode.left=null;
        if (word.compareToIgnoreCase(lastnode.item.keyword)>0)lastnode.right=null;
```

My question is: How does the parent.left/right pointer knows how to point at the new node after the rotation?

Answer (score 0):

As your parameter node and your returned node are the same, you could instead return the  new root of the subtree temp.

```
TreeNode rotateright(TreeNode node)
{
    TreeNode temp = node.left;
    node.left = temp.right;
    temp.right = node;
    return temp;
}
```

In case you cannot change the return statement, you could make a double linking by saving the parent of each node and checking which of the two parent's child the node is.

```
Node parent = node.parent;
if(parent.isLeftChild(node))
    parent.setLeftChild(temp);
else
    parent.setRightChild(temp);
```

An efficient workaround, in case your nodes are not accessed from outside the tree, is by switching only the values of the two upper nodes, so the root remains the root, and reordering the subtrees.

```
TreeNode rotateright(TreeNode node)
{
    Node left = left;
    Node leftLeft = node.left.left;
    Node leftRight = node.left.right;
    Node right = node.right;

    node.right = left;
    node.left = leftLeft;
    left.left = leftRight;
    left.right = right;

    switchValues(node, left);
}
```

Comment: I found a solution to the problem.I used a second pointer for the parent but that is what i was trying to avoid from the start. After enough time of nerve-breaking searching i succumbed to it and stepped back. P.S. return couldn't be changed.